# For running CLLocation function through Firebase, how would you structure the index.js file for it?

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, firebase-realtime-database, cllocationmanager

I am getting the CLLocation in the app and want to run it over firebase instead. I've followed the npm and node installation and now in my index.js file, I don't know how to put the function that is currently in the client code.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   {


    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
    latestLocation = ["latitude" : locValue.latitude, "longitude" : locValue.longitude]
    let lat = locValue.latitude
    let lon = locValue.longitude
    dict = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
    print("dict", dict)


    if let locationDictionary = latestLocation {
        databaseRef.child("people").child(uid).child("Coordinates").setValue(locationDictionary)

    }


}
```

Comment: are you using react native?

Comment: @Talha Nay, don't know anything about it other than it is from Facebook. I'm using Xcode/Swift

Comment: okay, bear with me please, i think i might need more of an understanding of your setup. so you have some swift code in which you're getting location. and now you want to pass this to a JS file? is this JS file for a website or something? Or is it that you are running a Node JS backend? could you share the current contents of the index JS file?